# Refactoring based on OPEN CLOSE PRINCIPLE- C#

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I have some code to write `Error Logs` to different places like `Console/SignalR Messages/Text File`.

The code is as follows:-

```
public class Logger
    {
    public void WriteToLog(string message, LogType logType)
    {
        switch (logType)
        {
            case LogType.Console:
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                break;

            case LogType.SignalR:
                // Code to send message to SignalR Hub
                break;

            case LogType.File:
                // Code to write in .txt file
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Where my `LogType` is a simple Enum as below:-

```
public enum LogType
{
    Console,
    SignalR,
    File
}
```

But, when I think of Open-Close Principle, I am not getting optimal solution for it.

Edit:

I need to refactor my code as per open close principle. I need to optimize it, so that I don't need to Modify `WriteToLog` method once any `LogType` gets added.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté:- I need to refactor my code as per open close principle. I need to optimize it, so that I don't need to Modify `WriteToLog` method once any `LogType` gets added.

Comment: Look at realisation of this principle in [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) project. It allow to define appenders in configuration file.

Comment: I'd say this sounds like a school assignment and you shouldn't shoot yorself in the foot by blindly pasting it here instead of thinking about it yourself and learning something. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface which will implement your logic for Logging:-
Say:

```
public interface ILogger {
        void LogMessage(string message);
    }
```

Create a new class for all message type in place of Enum, later stages if any new LogType gets added, respective class can be included without changing your existing Logic:

```
public class SignalRLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void LogMessage(string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();//your Implementaion here
        }
    }
```

Now, your implementation would be very similar as below:-

```
public class Logger
    {
        ILogger _logger;

        public Logger(ILogger messageLogger)
        {
            _logger = messageLogger;
        }

        public void Log(string message)
        {
            _logger.LogMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You should create an interface from which you can make many implementations, e.g. an `ILogger` interface with `Warning`, `Error` methods etc.

Then you would create an implementation per logging type (one for console, one for SignalR etc). You could then inject the `ILogger` into any type that requires it (or another approach is to use a static field and resolve the logger through a static log manager type).

You might also want to consider a library such as [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) which already provides an interface and several implementations already available, e.g. NLog, log4net etc.

Another consideration is whether you wish to mix business logic and logging code. Other alternatives are an AOP approach ([PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) is one option) or [semantic logging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/agile/embracing-semantic-logging).